# Delete text from specific point

Tags: python

I want to delete a part of a text that may vary from a specific point in python

Ex:

lksalksapointdlksla
Erase everything before "point"
pointdlksla

kljkghglpointsdfasfsd
Erase everything before "point"
pointsdfasfsd

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it:

```
text = "kljkghglpointsdfasfsd"
text = text.split("point")[1]
print(text)
```

Comment: Note that for multiple `point`s in the string, this will only return the part between the first and second `point`. `test.split("point", 1)` will split only once.

Answer (score 0):

I will use `.find()` and string slicing:

```
s = 'lksalksapointdlksla'
s = s[s.find('point'):]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```py
import re

regex = r"(?P<before>.*)(point)(?P<after>.*)"

test_str = "lksalksapointdlksla"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

You can then use the `before` and `after` group to do as you please.